# Highstock charts - change position of rangeselector From and To inputs

Tags: highcharts

I am using the default Highcharts single series stock chart: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo.

I am trying to hide the "From" and "To" label from the date range input boxes up top right. I then want to insert a "-" between the two input fields.

I am hiding the "From" and "To" labels by:

```
labelStyle: {
              display: 'none'
            },
```

This removes the labels (and also the Zoom label, which is fine for my exercise) but the space reserved for the labels still exists. How do I go about removing the space reserved for these labels and pushing the two input fields closer together and inserting a "-" between them?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rlsaj/b9sfeLpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not available, so you can post your suggestion [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastian. I managed to get myself out of trouble by using some jQuery. $('.highcharts-input-group > g:nth-child(2)').attr('transform', 'translate(55,0)'); // very hacky

Comment: Yes you are right, anyway, good to now that workaround is possible ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the label values by using the rangeSelectorFrom and rangeSelectorTo properties from the language settings. But to be honest I don't know if this affects the consumed space between the inputs.

See: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang.rangeSelectorFrom